# What's the cooldown on Geralt's Medallion?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'll admit it - sometimes I touch myself.  My Witcher medallion, I mean.  Afterwards, there's this orange glow that surrounds nearby items.  However, sometimes when I touch it, nothing happens.  This is disappointing to no end.  Sometimes I resort to rapidly touching my... medallion in the hopes that something will happen, but this seems counter-productive.

The loading screens seem to indicate that there's a cooldown on Geralt's medallion's power, but how long is it?  Is there any indication when it's ready for use again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a 10-second cooldown between Medallion uses.
When it's ready, the Witcher Medallion next to your health bar will glow and pulse yellow, like so:
[image: Medallion ready to use]
When it's on cooldown, the Medallion has no glow, like so:
[image: Medallion on cool down]